# Choropleth maps in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, folium, choropleth

This is my dataset:

[image: This is my dataset]

This is my code:

[image: This is my code]

I'm getting this error:

[image: I'm getting this error]

For those who need the code:

```py
canada_geo = r'canada_provinces.json'
# create a plain world map
canada_map = folium.Map(location=[56.1304, -106.3468], zoom_start=2, tiles='Mapbox Bright')
print(canada_geo)`

    canada_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=canada_geo,
    data=canada,
    columns=['abbreviation', 'Population'],
    key_on="features.properties.Abbreviation",
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Population'
)

# display map
canada_map
```

Comment: Please paste the code here and don't just put screenshot, this will get a user the ability to try it locally. Also the error would be nice to have in a written form, but I'm not sure that it's that bad

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting of the code but I've added it.

Comment: you can post the code here by surrounding it with ```, the idea is that someone can just copy paste it (or part of it) into an editor, and trying it locally.
you can see an example inside of your answer

Comment: `canada_geo = r'canada_provinces.json'

canada_map = folium.Map(location=[56.1304, -106.3468], zoom_start=2, tiles='Mapbox Bright')
print(canada_geo)
canada_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=canada_geo,
    data=canada,
    columns=['abbreviation', 'Population'],
    key_on="features.properties.Abbreviation",
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Population'
    )

canada_map`

Comment: link to the json file [https://github.com/tapsibz/CapstoneIBM/blob/master/canada_provinces.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at this line:

```
key_on="features.properties.Abbreviation",
```

The right code is:

```
key_on="feature.properties.Abbreviation",
```

and you get:

[image]